# Why do Ava and the others at the orphanage speak English?

Tags: warrior-nun

Although much of the first season of *Warrior Nun* is set in Spain, most of the dialogue is in English. Now, this makes sense to a certain extent. The titular nuns themselves are an international group, and since English is the *de facto* international language in many contexts, it makes sense that they would prefer it. The same logically applies to Doctor Salvius and her fellow physicists, international backers, and mercenaries, or to communication between the various members of the Catholic Church, or even to a bunch of world-traveler *okupas* like Ava's friends.

We definitely know that there is not a translation convention in play, a la *Mulan* or *Doctor Who*, because there are scenes where characters actually speak in Spanish, subtitled of course. For instance, the priest who oversees the order of nuns has a modestly lengthy chat with a local bar owner in said language. Random people on the street tend to speak Spanish in the show. In other words, when the characters are speaking English, they are actually speaking English. While the *stylistic* choice to have almost no Spanish dialogues in a show set in Andalucia<sup>1</sup> seems unusual, from a story perspective all of this at least makes a certain kind of sense.

However, then we have Ava, and her orphanage. Ava speaks English in the orphanage with an American accent, and preferentially speaks English with Spanish-speakers like the aforementioned priest or her young friend Diego<sup>2</sup>, but she was supposed to have arrived at the orphanage as a child (9 or 10, or even younger, if I recall). Possibly her speaking English could be explained by the fact that the nun who oversees the orphanage also speaks English (with an accent from somewhere around the British isles or Ireland), but the fact that an orphanage in the middle of Andalucia is run by a British or Irish woman who speaks English with her charges, and with the other nuns in the orphanage for that matter, just raises further questions.

So, in short, why does everyone at the orphanage speak English? Is there an in-story reason for this?

<sub>1: From personal experience, I can attest that the average person there does not speak much English at all, certainly compared to Madrid, to say nothing of e.g. the Netherlands.</sub>

<sub>2: The actor who plays her was born in Portugal, grew up in Brazil, and does not seem to have lived in the US, but her Portuguese accent is so subtle that I frankly was unsure whether she was American before looking that information up. She also speaks Spanish, which makes it rather confusing that she does not speak Spanish with e.g. the priest, even when he speaks it with others.</sub>